# Write a program that sees the New Year in itself

Tags: quine, code-golf

Write the smallest program that maps strings injectively to outputs and maps itself to 2020.

To be clear, your program \$p\$ must have the following properties:

1. every possible input string \$s\$ has a well-defined output \$p(s)\$,
2. for every pair of strings \$s\$ and \$t\$ with \$s\neq t\$, it holds that \$p(s)\neq p(t)\$, and
3. \$p(p)=2020\$.

Be sure to explain why your submission satisfies properties 1 and 2. For property 3, the output can be a string or any type of number.

**Edit 1:** Programs need to be proper quine variants. Reading the source code is not allowed.

**Edit 2:** Note that as a consequence of property 2, it holds that \$p(s)\neq p(p)\$ for every \$s\neq p\$.

Comment: _every possible input string_ Can we support only ASCII?

Comment: @LuisMendo - yes, provided ASCII is the alphabet of the language that your program is written in.

Comment: Do programs need to be proper quine variants or is reading the source code allowed?

Comment: Is a function acceptable or must we write a full program?

Comment: @FlipTack - Thanks for the clarifying question. No reading the source code. I edited the post to reflect this.

Comment: @RobinRyder - A function is acceptable.

Comment: How do any of these requirements imply being a quine?  If you wrote a whole program that (for example) reads from stdin, you'd get `p(p)` by running `./my_program < my_source.c` with the user feeding the program a copy of the source (as opposed to any other input), right?  Or for a function, just `uint32_t map(char *)`.  Except `uint32_t` can't work- by the pigeonhole principle that would only allow 2^32 possible input strings, not arbitrary length.  Or did you mean that if you want your source code as a constant to compare against, you'd need a quine technique to embed it?

Answer (score 54):

## awk, 4 bytes

The structure of an awk program is *`pattern { action }`*. If *pattern* evaluates to true, *{ action }* is performed. If *{ action }* is omitted, the default is to output the current input record.

Code:

```
2020
```

As `2020` always evaluates to true, the program always prints it's input, therefore satisfying properties 1. and 2. When the input is the program itself it satisfies property 3. \$p(p)=2020\$ — even \$p(p)=p\$.

Some test cases:

```
$ echo 2020 | awk '2020'
2020
$ echo 0 | awk '2020'
0
$ echo "" | awk '2020'

$ echo foo | awk '2020'
foo
```

Would've been more glorious back in the good old days:

```
$ echo 1 | awk '1'
1
```

Comment: polyglot with [perl5 -p](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/9/IwMgAQnIZcHGl5ef/yy8oyczPK/6vWwAA)

Comment: Nice James, thank you for sharing the same :)

Comment: Also polyglot with [Perl 6 `-p`](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH7/9/IwMgAQnIZcHGl5ef/yy8oyczPK/6vWwAA).

Comment: In some other stack-based languages, like Golfscript, the code ```20``` would suffice since it auto-concatenates the stack to print out on output.

Answer (score 12):

## JavaScript (ES6), 23 bytes

Returns either the input string with a leading \$0\$, or \$2020\$ if the input is the program.

```javascript
f=s=>s=='f='+f?2020:0+s
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0osSyxOLsosKNHNy09J/f8/zbbY1q7Y1lY9zVZdO83eyMDIwMpAu/h/cn5ecX5Oql5OfrpGmoaSR2pOTr6OQnh@UU6KopKmJheaPEgfFmEcpgNV/gcA)

---

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), 76 bytes

Generates a unique BigInt by using each byte of the input string, then applies a XOR to the result in such a way that \$f(f)=2020\$.

```javascript
f=s=>(g=s=>Buffer(s).every(b=>t=t<<8n|BigInt(b),t=1n)&&t)(s)^g('f='+f)^2020n
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0osSyxOLsosKNHNy09J/f8/zbbY1k4jHUQ6laalpRZpFGvqpZalFlVqJNnaldiW2NhY5NU4ZaZ75pVoJGnqlNga5mmqqZVoAtXFpWuop9mqa6dpxhkZGBnk/U/OzyvOz0nVy8lP10jTUPJIzcnJ11EIzy/KSVFU0tTkQpOnpt1A4/8DAA)

Comment: The first one does not match criteria 2, as it will output the same result for different input strings

Comment: @Skyler Please note that the input is a string and so is `0+s`. If `a` and `b` are 2 distinct strings, so are `0+a` and `0+b`.

Comment: I think this doesn't satisfy the "do not read the source code" condition, right?

Comment: @TomášZato-ReinstateMonica Last time I checked, I think Dennis' answer about that was the most upvoted, but it seems like [we still don't have a clear concensus](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/13634/58563). (Also, this requirement did not exist at the time I answered the challenge.)

Comment: You can check the revision change on https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/revisions/197679/2 which was at 2020-01-04 19:36:35Z while this answer was posted on 2020-01-04 17:08:36Z - almost 2 hours and a half after this answer was posted. On that edit, the tag "quine" as added as well.

Answer (score 7):

## [Python 3.8 (pre-release)](https://docs.python.org/3.8/), <s>81</s> <s>60</s> <s>59</s> <s>57</s> 56 bytes

-21 Thanks to Jo King

Outputs 2020 if the input matches the program, otherwise the input concatenated to itself 5 time (eg. `abc` becomes `abcabcabcabcabc`)

```python
exec(a:='print(5*[i:=input(),404][i=="exec(a:=%r)"%a])')
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM7YoKPr/P7UiNVkj0cpWvaAoM69Ew1QrOtPKNjOvoLREQ1PHxMAkNjrT1lYJpkq1SFNJNTFWU12TfJ0A)

---

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 56 bytes

Outputs 2020 if the input matches the program, otherwise the input concatenated to itself 5 time (eg. `abc` becomes `abcabcabcabcabc`)

```python
a='i=input();print 5*[i,404][i=="a=%r;exec a"%a]';exec a
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/r/P9FWPdM2M6@gtERD07qgKDOvRMFUKzpTx8TAJDY609ZWKdFWtcg6tSI1WSFRSTUxVh3K/v9fSUmJXM1ArQA)

---

## [Python 3.8 (pre-release)](https://docs.python.org/3.8/), <s>77</s> <s>67</s> 65 bytes

-10 Thanks to Jo King

Outputs 2020 if the input matches the program, otherwise the input concatenated to itself 5 time (eg. `abc` becomes `abcabcabcabcabc`)

```python
lambda s:5*[s,404][s==(a:='lambda s:5*[s,404][s==(a:=%r)%%a]')%a]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM7YoKPqfpmCrEPM/JzE3KSVRodjKVCu6WMfEwCQ2utjWViPRylYdt5RqkaaqamKsuiaQ@F9QlJlXopGmkZlXUFqioamp@d/IAAA)

Answer (score 7):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/) `-n`, 45 bytes

Based on one of the classic Ruby quines, `_="_=%p;puts _%%_";puts _%_`. Prints `2020` if the input is the source, otherwise prints the Ruby representation of the input (encapsulated in quotes, various characters like `"` and `\` are escaped, etc.)

```ruby
_="_=%p;p$_==_%%_ ?2020:$_";p$_==_%_ ?2020:$_
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KypNqvz/P95WKd5WtcC6QCXe1jZeVTVewd7IwMjASiVeCSaGECJR@b/8gpLM/Lzi/7p5AA)

Answer (score 6):

## [GolfScript](http://www.golfscript.com/golfscript/), 2 bytes

```
20
```

This is a refined solution to James Brown's solutions.

If the input is 20 [source code], prints 2020 - otherwise prints [string]+20, which is unique and easily reversible.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8/PSStOLsosKPn/38gAhAE)

Answer (score 3):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 16 bytes

```
“Ṿ;⁾v`³⁽¥ŒṾ⁼?”v`
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8//9Rw5yHO/dZP2rcV5ZwaPOjxr2Hlh6dBBR51LjH/lHD3LKE/0SoAQA)

A full program that takes a string as its input. It outputs an unevaluated Jelly version of the input unless provided with itself, in which case it outputs 2020.

Thanks to @JonathanAllan for pointing out a flaw in my original version!

### Explanation

```
 “Ṿ;⁾v`³⁽¥ŒṾ⁼?”v` | Evaluate as Jelly code the following, using itself as the argument:
  Ṿ               | - Unevaluate (effectively wraps string back into “”
   ;⁾v`           | - Append "v`"
       ³    ⁼?    | - If equal to the program’s argument:
        ⁽¥Œ       | - Then: 2020 (compressed integer)
           Ṿ      | - Else: Unevaluated version of the program’s original argument
```

Comment: Hmm, not sure it's valid without bracketing or something - [TIO](https://tio.run/##ASsA1P9qZWxsef//4oCc4bm@O@KBvnZgwrPigb3CpcWST@KBvD/igJ12YP///9@k) EDIT - how about [this](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8//9Rw5yHO/dZP2rcV5ZwaPOjxr2Hlh6ddHTSw50zHjXusX/UMLcs4T9RqgA)?

Comment: @JonathanAllan I don’t follow. Although it will follow standard Jelly implicit printing rules, the output should still be unique for any given input. The question doesn’t seem to put any further criteria on what the output consists of. Thanks for your suggestion; while it works, I’m still not sure why I can’t just continue to use `O`.

Comment: There is an s (`ߤ`) for which p(s) = p(p) (`2020`)

Comment: Oh I see. I now also follow your comment to the question. For now, I’ll update to your version if that’s ok. Thanks!

Comment: @JonathanAllan I’ve gone with `Ṿ` which should work ok. Any thoughts?

Comment: Was just about to suggest it!

Comment: @RobinRyder only when provided as an integer. When provided as a string (which is the spec), it yields `“2020”` which != `2020`

Comment: @NickKennedy Right, I had missed that input was restricted to strings.

Answer (score 3):

## [Raku](https://github.com/nxadm/rakudo-pkg), 47 bytes

```perl6
<say "<$_>~~.EVAL"eq($!=get)??2020!!@$!>~~.EVAL
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH7/9@mOLFSQclGJd6urk7PNczRRym1UENF0TY9tUTT3t7IwMhAUdFBRREmS7IGAA)

Outputs `2020` if the input matches the program, otherwise the input surrounded in brackets.

Answer (score 2):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), <s>190</s> <s>196</s> <s>194</s> <s>192</s> <s>180</s> 176 bytes

Thanks to [Jo King](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/76162/jo-king) for pointing out a bug.

Trailing newline seems accepted in some other answers, so will use that to fix a bug pointed out by [NieDzejkob](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/55934/niedzejkob). (Also -12 bytes thanks to the same.)

-4 bytes thanks to @ceilingcat.

Assumes little-endian, ASCII, `sizeof(int) >= 4`, all the good stuff.

Outputs the input string preceded by a dollar sign, unless given its own source code, in which case it outputs `2020`.

```c
*s="*s=%c%s%1$c,u[99]={'0202'};f(int*t){puts(bcmp(u+2,t,sprintf(u+2,s,34,s))?putchar(36),t:u);}",u[99]={'0202'};f(int*t){puts(bcmp(u+2,t,sprintf(u+2,s,34,s))?putchar(36),t:u);}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S9ZNT07@/1@r2FYJiFWTVYtVDVWSdUqjLS1jbavVDYwMjNRrrdM0MvNKtEo0qwtKS4o1kpJzCzRKtY10SnSKC4qAMmlgXrGOsYlOsaamPVBRckZikYaxmaZOiVWppnWtErUN/A9UpJCbmJmnoclVzcWZpqGUkZqlpGkNZgKtMICxYTTQczG09GEM1b0IcnntfwA)

Comment: which is a different output than the empty string

Comment: The requirement is that no two distinct inputs should have the same output.

Comment: @JoKing Good point! (Hopefully) Corrected now.

Comment: @NieDzejkob The number will vary between implementations no doubt. Cheers!

Comment: @gastropner Now 2020 corresponds to the input of the old program...

Comment: [172 bytes](https://tio.run/##S9ZNT07@/1@r2FYJiFWTVYtVDVWSdUqjLS1jbavVDYwMjNRrrdM0SjSriwuKMvNK0jRKtY10inWMTXSKNa0LSkuKNYpLipJzC8DiJZr2QKHkjMQiDWMzTZ0Sq1JN61ol6hr3H6hNITcxM09Dk6uaizNNQykjNUtJ0xrMBFpgAGPDaKDHYmjnuxgqew/k6tr/AA)

Comment: @NieDzejkob Hopefully fixed. The 182 bytes one works only if `sizeof(int) == sizeof(char*)` (or by luck).

Comment: @gastropner Ok, then [180 bytes](https://tio.run/##S9ZNT07@/1@r2FYJiFWTVYtVDVWSdUqjLS1jbavVDYwMjNRrrdM0MvNKtEo0q4sLioCsNI1SbSOdYh1jE51iTeuC0pJijeKSouTcArB4iaY9UCg5I7FIw9hMU6fEqlTTulaJ@kb@B2pTyE3MzNPQ5Krm4kzTUMpIzVLStAYzgZYYwNgwGujBGNr6MoYG3gS5vvY/AA)

Comment: @ceilingcat Neato!

Answer (score 2):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), 28 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
"34çìD«QiŽ7ìëû"34çìD«QiŽ7ìëû
```

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f9fydjk8PLDa1wOrQ7MPLrX/PCaw6sP78YqSIpaAA) or [verify a few more test cases](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/V9TVnl4gr2SwqO2SQpK9v@VjE0OLz@8xuXQ6sDMo3vND685vPrwbqyC/2t1SFDNRaxSrpLU4hIuIwMjA67EpGSuRK5EEEoEAA).

**Explanation:**

```python
"34çìD«QiŽ7ìëû"            # Push this string
               34ç         # Push 34, and convert it to a character: '"'
                  ì        # Prepend it in front of the string
                   D«      # Append a copy of the string to itself
                     Qi    # If it's equal to the (implicit) input:
                       Ž7ì #  Push compressed integer 2020
                      ë    # Else:
                       û   #  Palindromize the (implicit) input
                           # (after which the result is output implicitly)
```

[See this 05AB1E tip of mine (section *How to compress large integers?*)](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/166851/52210) to understand why `Ž7ì` is `2020`.

Comment: [Might work](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/V9TVnl4gr2SwqO2SQpK9v@VjE0OLz@8xuXQ6gt7ju41P7zm0GosQv91kBQGZoJFD68@vBurIBdxZnKVpBaXcBkZGBlwJSYlcyVyJYJQIgA "05AB1E – Try It Online") ... only problem is an empty string?

Comment: @ExpiredData The `м` should be `K`, otherwise any input containing only characters of the input (i.e. `DD`) would also result in `2020`. But apart from that the empty string is indeed a problem I'm not sure how to overcome. :(

Comment: @ExpiredData the empty string is far from the only problem. Appending the code to any string doesn't change the output ([example](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/V9TVnl4gr2SwqO2SQpK9v@VjE0OLz@8xuXQau@je80Przm0GlPkv87/pJzEDGKUcoEUAgA)). It seems highly unlikely you can make something injective with either `м` or `K`, since those fundamentally lose information.

Comment: Yeah @Grimmy thanks great point

Answer (score 1):

## Java 10, 128 bytes

```java
s->{var t="s->{var t=%c%s%1$c;t=t.format(t,34,t);return t.equals(s)?2020:0+s;}";t=t.format(t,34,t);return t.equals(s)?2020:0+s;}
```

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##rZDPSsNAEIfveYohNLDBdonVk0v0CayHHq2HyXYrmyabujMJSMmzx40G9CKh0Msyf76B77cldrgq98dBV0gEz2jdOQKwjo0/oDawGVuAl6I0mkGLLXvr3oFSFeZ9FB5iZKthAw5yGGj1eO7QA@fxb5nohJLbhVacszw0vkYWvLy7X3KqvOHWO2BpPlqsSFD6tM7W2UN2Q6qPL74Y1Oh0aosqOE1qXWP3UIdok/3rG2D6k2v7SWxq2bQsT2HFlRNOavHHfXeNHLvLg8Tp9xf/rziisxAb4lkICz3LTEAf9cMX)

**Explanation:**

[quine](/questions/tagged/quine) part of the explanation:

- `var t` contains the unformatted source code
- `%s` is used to input this String into itself with `t.format(...)`
- `%c`, `%1$c`, and the `34` are used to format the double quotes
- `t.format(t,34,t)` puts it all together

Challenge part of the explanation:

- `t.equals(s)` checks if the input-String is equal to the source code
- `?2020`: if it is, return `2020` as result
- `:0+s`: if not, return the input-String with a prepended 0 as result instead

Answer (score 1):

## [Pyth](https://github.com/isaacg1/pyth), <sup><s>26</s></sup> 23 bytes

Outputs 2020 if the input matches the program, otherwise the input concatenated to itself 2020 time (eg. ab becomes ababab...ababab)

```
*2020|qjN B"*2020|qjN B
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsyfj/X8vIwMigpjDLT8FJCYn9/7@SkhIOOaDMv/yCksz8vOL/uikA)

### Explanation

```
*2020|qjN B"*2020|qjN B
          B"*2020|qjN B : Evaluates to ("*2020|qjN B", "*2020|qjN B")
       jN               : join with '"' as seperator (will be source code)
     |q                 : True if source is equal to input else input
*2020                   : Multiply by 2020 (i.e. True -> 2020, input -> 2020 * input)
```

---

## [Pyth](https://github.com/isaacg1/pyth), 21 bytes

Not sure if the following solution is valid, it will only work if the year is 2020.

```
*.d3|qjN B"*.d3|qjN B
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsyfj/X0svxbimMMtPwUkJwfz/X0lJCasMUPxffkFJZn5e8X/dFAA)

Answer (score 0):

## [J](http://jsoftware.com/), 56 bytes

```
".a=.}:0 :0
echo@>2020[^:(]-:'".a=.}:0 :0',LF,a&[)1!:1[3
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y/r/X0kv0Vav1spAwcqAKzU5I9/BzsjAyCA6zkojVtdKHUlWXcfHTSdRLVrTUNHKMNqYfJ0A)

A full program. Unless provided with itself prints each character on a separate line.

Answer (score 0):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), 24 bytes

```
OvA="¶`OvA=`+Q+A?2020:U³
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0osKPn/37/M0Vbp0LYEEJ2gHajtaG9kYGRgFXpo8///6rgl1QE)

### Explanation

Outputs 2020 if the input matches the program, otherwise the input 3 times (eg. ab becomes ababab)

```
OvA="¶`OvA=`+Q+A?2020:U³
  A="¶`OvA=`+Q+A?2020:U³  // Set value of A to "¶`OvA=`+Q+A?2020:U³"
Ov                        // Evaluate A as japt code
      `OvA=`+Q+A          // Concatenate "OvA=", '"' and A (Q = '"')
     ¶          ?2020:U³  // If equal to input then 2020 else input concatenated to itself 3 times
```